# Dynamic memory allocation for a 2D array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to understand how dynamic allocation of a 2D array works internally in C++.

While allocating memory dynamically for a 2D array of type `int` and size `m * n`, we write:

`int **arr = new int * [m];`

and then run a loop across the size `m` until we reach the number of columns, `n`, allocating an array to each pointer.

I don't understand why we are assuming that when we create the array of pointers, it assumes it to be in a row format. Why can it not be in column format? If it is in column format, then when we iterate through it allocating arrays, we would then be allocating the rows and hence the order of the 2D array will reverse, instead of `m * n` it will become `n * m`.

How does the system know with this statement - `int **arr = new int * [m]` - that it has to be allocated in the row format and corresponding columns would be allocated later?

Comment: And you missed to ask a concrete question here ...

Comment: `How does the system know` It doesn't, and it doesn't matter. All you're doing is allocating an array to hold arrays. Whether you treat them as rows->columns or columns->rows is up to you.

Comment: Note: That is a way to simulate a 2-d array with dynamic allocation. It is not identical to a 2-d array. There are other, arguably better ways to do it. It is not compatible with code that expects an actual 2-d array.

Comment: Look up the terms row-major and column-major. Some languages are set up one way, others the other. C++ is natively row major, however it is possible to build constructs that are column-major. It is also possible to reinterpret rows as cols and vice versa, but that can be confusing. Consistency is necessary and the usual expectation in C++ is that things are expected to be row major.

Answer (score 0):

The standard C does allocate multidimensional "C arrays" in a single block, not anything like what the text described.  So `int arr[3][4]` would be allocated (equivalently) as `int arr[12]` and `arr[2][1]` would be accessed as `arr[2*4+1]`.

However this will hit memory fragmentation (block too big to be allocated) even for small matrices so packages typically allocate entire columns or rows independently as your text describes.

Fortran, in contrary, will allocate matrices by rows so you need to be recognizant of that while coding. There is nothing like that in the C language.

So the internal allocation and access of individual elements depends entirely on what package you are using.

Comment: Yeah, I know C allocates multidimensional arrays, just in the dynamic memory allocation, I was trying to understand how an array of pointers is first created and then the address in those pointers are the addresses of 1d arrays, respectively while assuming that the first array of pointers is stored in a row form compulsarily.

Answer (score 0):

Its up to you to decide whether you want a row-major or column-major 2D array allocation scheme. In your code : `**arr = new int * [m]` m can be count of columns or rows. System has nothing to do with it.

What is more important is when would you choose row-major vs column-major. This might be dependent on the algorithm you choose, or on performance requirements. For example if you access your 2D array more by iterating rows, then row-major will be more efficient as CPU will cache rows in more efficient  cache. On the other hand if you iterate your array by columns then choose column-major.

There is also other way to allocate memory to use it as a 2d array - by calling `int* arr = new int[m*n];` Then indexing with `arr[i + j*m]` assuming m is for rows.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not a 2D array, but a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays. It is up to the application to decide whether these represent the rows or the columns of a matrix.

In C and C++, 2D arrays can be defined, and are stored in row-major order, meaning that the elements that are stored contiguously have successive second index. A[1][0] is immediately followed by A[1][1] in memory. Given that the first [second] index is usually referred-to as denoting the row [column], this justifies the row-major naming.

For coherence, an array of pointers to arrays should rather correspond to the successive rows.